# Beginner level: Help in learning Kalman Smoother (Part 1)

Tags: time-series, self-study, smoothing, kalman-filter, filter

[Parameter estimation of Linear Dynamical system](http://www.tristanfletcher.co.uk/LDS.pdf) is a tutorial which explains Kalman Filter, Smoothing, and Expectation Maximization. I have followed the derivation for Kalman Filter. But cannot understand the smoothing. I have read textbooks and many other resources including the references cited in this document but failed to understand how the smoothing equations are derived. Particularly in this case document, Section 6 mentions the Smoother. In the E Step, the smoother is calculated and the result of the Smoothing is included in the estimates obtained in the Maximization step. For the model,

$h(t) = \mathbf{A^T} h(t-1) + \eta^h(t)$

$v(t) = \mathbf{B^T}h(t) + \eta^v(t)$

$\eta^h(t) = N(0,Q), \eta^v(t) =N(0,R)$

The log likelihood is $Q= - \sum_{t=1}^{} \big(\frac{1}{2}[v(t) - Bh(t))'R^{-1}[v(t)-Bh(t)] \big) - \frac{T}{2} \log |R| - \sum_{t=2}^T \big( \frac{1}{2} [h(t)' - Ah(t-1)]'Q^{-1}[h(t) - Ah(t-1)]\big) - \frac{T-2}{2} \log |Q| -\frac{1}{2} {[h_1 - \pi_1]}' V_1^{-1}[h_1 - \pi_1] - \frac{1}{2} \log |V_1| - \frac{T(p+2) \log 2 \pi}{2}$

where $\pi_1, V$ is the mean and variance of the initial condition of $h$.

Section 6: I cannot understand how the expressions 2--6 in Pg7 have come and what is the technique of including this in the M step. It shall be really helpful if the derivation of any one expression and the plugging in of the smoothed estimate into the M step is illustrated.

Comment: Link to tutorial  does not work (possibly it was the same as "The Kalman filter explained" here: https://www.tristanfletcher.co.uk/tutorials/ ).  The topic refers to Kalman smoother  while the question seems to be asking about EM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me take a few steps back. EM algorithm is not required in a Kalman Filter if the design matrices(A, B, Q, R, etc) are known. They are known only if you know which physical system you are modelling from the beginning. If not then you will have to estimate these matrices. Filtering and smoothing operations are performed assuming that these matrices are already known.

EM utilizes the filtering or smoothing equations by starting with some random initial values of design matrices and then running the filtering equations (expectation step) and then lowering the prediction error (maximization step). It is possible to replace filtering equations with smoothing equations in the above procedure. You get to choose either filtering or smoothing (To be very precise filtering is the first step of smoothing. Hence smoothing is like an add-on). The difference is filtering only uses past values, smoothing on the other hand takes also future values into consideration.

[EM Derivation for Kalman Filter](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MARSS/vignettes/EMDerivation.pdf) is probably the most complete derivation of the EM procedure for Kalman Filter/Smoother.

To sum up, when design matrices are known, you run either filtering or smoothing equations to execute the filter. If matrices are not known you execute the filter by either filtering or smoothing equations then modify the matrices so that the results of the previous operation are improved. You repeat this procedure until the matrices don't change much. And this is called the EM procedure. The good thing is Kalman EM has neat solutions for the derivatives in the maximization procedure therefore you don't need numerical techniques for maximization.

Comment: Thank you for providing this link and the reasoning for applying Smoother. In my case, the deign matrices are unknown. I skimmed through the link and Still still some parts are unclear. Could you please share your insights? (1) If the coefficients/matrices and the covariances are unknown then how come we feed the Equation into the Kalman or any other filter? That is how do we know the physical structure if these parameters are unknown? HOw do we assume or know whether the model is autoregressive? It could have been Moving average

Comment: (2)COming back to the Smoothing, different resources have different equations for smoothing. Reason depends on the model, and likelihood expression, hence the EM equations also differ. I am following the original paper by  Zoubin Ghahramani, Parameter estimation for Linear dynamical system, since my model is exactly the one which is explained here. How is the Equations for smoothing coming? Smoothing is done when all the observations are available (so offline method). Can you please explain any one of them? Thank you.

Comment: "feed the equation into the Kalman". This sentence is meaningless. A filter is a specific model. Kalman is a model. If your data doesn't follow the filter's model then the filter will not work as expected. There are cases when the real world physical dynamics are known, for example falling of a rock, we have speed, acceleration equations. In such cases you can set up the Kalman filter and set the matrices to follow these equations. In other cases, you have to start by saying "I don't know the matrices but I am fairly sure that my data follows the Kalman structure of equations."

Comment: So you start by assuming that the structure of equations are suitable for your data, but parameters(matrices, covariances) not known. EM helps you estimate these parameters from data. Equations change due to (1) whether they can accommodate missing values, (2) what are the starting point assumptions. Filter helps you discover the hidden state. The initial value of the hidden state is also not known. You may supply it yourself or you may also ask EM to estimate this as well. That's why equations may change depending on author, but in general they are similar.

Comment: Autoregressive is a model. Moving average is a model. Kalman is an autoregressive model plus an observation equation and noise on top. So it is richer than AR model. Also don't confuse with estimating the parameters of Kalman vs running the Kalman filter. When you are estimating the parameters you will need some data ready at hand. When running the filter you can run it on new previously unobserved data. For smoothing you need to wait and accumulate more data, compared to filter where next data point is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. One last Question. You mentioned that Kalman is an AR model. How do we represent an MA model using Kalman? Can you please provide a link or just the equation here.

Comment: Beauty of Kalman is that it is a simple model yet accommodates many situations and there are libraries and tools already available to train them and run them, albeit a little difficult. When you change the model you need to figure out how to train it and run it from square 1. But if you make observation error 0 then you end up with pure AR. In that case you can easily add MA, but then it will be standard ARMA not Kalman, which you also have tools for.

Comment: I have posted another Question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140405/beginner-level-how-to-plug-in-the-smoothing-equations-into-e-step-part-2 in continuation to my problem. Can you please have a look? Thank you for your time and effort.